# MySQL insert issue - works on local machine but not server, regardless of permissions

Tags: php, mysql, insert

A problem has come up, and it seems too general to be able to search on here or Google.  The issue is that I have a `PHP` app running just fine on my own machine.  I've exported the database to the server, as well as uploaded all files.  The database usernames are the same on both the server and my machine, and so are the passwords.  I've tried providing the user with full permissions, but this changes nothing.

The SQL query is:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, date, access_level) 
VALUES('test', 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c087333d391e987982fbbd333', 'magista@hotmail.com', '20110329235016', 1)
```

As I said, the query should be fine, given that it works on my own machine.  I was thinking there might be some sort of file permissions issue, but I have no idea.

Does anybody have any tips?  Anything to get me on the right track for solving this problem would be helpful.

Thanks,

Paragon

Comment: First step - look at `mysql_error()`

Comment: What is your problem? are you getting any error?

Comment: Other first step: what is the actual problem? I'm assuming you can't log in. If that is the case, how is that password value created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I post after hours of frustration, and figure it out as soon as I post here.

In case anyone is interested, the issue was that the auto-increment setting on my primary key field did not import.  Therefore, despite importing everything I had, there was still an obvious issue with the database table.

Paragon

Comment: Good job. You can come back in two days  and accept your own answer as correct.